# Standard privacy terms for collecting email address, first name, surname

Tags: email, privacy, terms-of-service

Is there a standard set of terms that could be used to include (for UK website), that would cover me, asking a user for First name, surname, username, email address and an opt in for communications from me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to personal data, not UX

Comment: including a privacy statement, allowing access, how to include it, the wording, sign up mechanism - all relates to user experience.

Comment: your question as it stands is a purely legal one - if you could make it more specific as to the UX problem you have, I'm sure it would be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

since you say you're running a UK website, [the best reading you can do is on the ICO](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/) (which is among the better agencies worldwide when it comes to guidance imho).

You'll find pretty much all the answers you need. If you don't want to spend too much time educating yourself, you might be interested in the work I'm doing at [iubenda](http://www.iubenda.com), where we create software tools for online compliance. There are completely free tiers as well.

In general you'll want to cover at least the following sections as outlined by the ICO currently:

- your identity and, if you are not based in the UK, the identity of your nominated UK representative;
- the purpose or purposes for which you intend to process the information; and
- any extra information you need to give individuals in the circumstances to enable you to process the information fairly.

By the way, mid next year it will make sense to go over your privacy policy again, since a new data protection regulation will be governing these types of questions: the [GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/resources-and-support/data-protection-self-assessment/getting-ready-for-the-gdpr/).